# Integration With Netsuite From ASP.NET Through TBA(Token Base Authentication)

Tags: asp.net, netsuite

How to integrate ASP.NET application with NETSUITE restlet using TBA(TOKEN BASE AUTHENTICATIONS)

1- I have tried with HTTPRequest/response but it was working good with POSTMAN same request but in visual studio it returns 404(forbidden) Error in response !! but after 3 to 4 time rebuilt the solution it gives response correctly with same code ! I'm not getting the issue with code or request because it gives error 404 and also return response correctly without any trouble.

I want response correctly every time when i request for rest-let through visual studio ASP.NET

Comment: I'm guessing that you read the docs (https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_4247329078.html).  Outside of that, when I was building TBA connections for RESTlets, I used the login audit trail a lot to see why there were failures.  Almost every time, it was due to a bad timestamp.  The audit trail is your friend. :)

Comment: How i can use login audit trail  ? and what do you mean by bad timestamp ? and how could i do better in this ?

Comment: @W3BGUY in login audit trail the reason for failure in details column is : *InvalidSignature*

Comment: That's your problem, then.  You are not creating the signature correctly.  Did you review the docs on how to properly create one?

Comment: @W3BGUY i am just trying review different solution and does not review any doc properly !! kindly share the link if you know any doc that could help in this scenario

Comment: I shared the link in my first comment. ;)